# Why text pulse?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder why this text, although it is the same, is pulsating. Any ideas? Looks like a font rendering issue.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const elem =  document.querySelector('p');
  
  elem.style.display = elem.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}, 1000)
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

Comment: what does `setInterval` meant to do?

Comment: You're toggling the display `none` every second, so it "pulses" ;)

Comment: I understand what the js code is doing, the question is why the text is pulsating even though it is the same. Looks like a font rendering issue.

Comment: No, not the text `Test` itself, only its inline style property.

Comment: Looks like it toggling between bold and regular text.

Comment: Magnifying the snippet appears to lessen the effect which leads me to think that it may be due to anti-aliasing effects.

Comment: Beacuse the `p` is overlapping another `p` stressing out and looks bolder

Comment: @Viira What is "stressing out" in this context?

Comment: I mean if you draw a line again and again in a white paper it will look bolder ain't it same happens here

Comment: Modern fonts often have borders that have some translucency. So in this case, you might have a pixel that is 50% red on the edge for the first letter. Then, when you add another, that pixel will become 75% red. So it appears thicker. That's what I think at least.

Comment: @ShamPooSham It make sense. I will verify it, thanks.

Comment: @AnonimAnonim You can try turning off anti-aliasing on your computer and see if you still have the same effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that text normally is rendered anti-aliased, which means that you have pixels with different transparencies (and possibly also color) at the border of the font to get a smooth look:

[image]

The area around the font is therefore up to one pixel larger than it is perceived when you look at it. If you overlay the same text multiple times then it appears to be thicker because the pixels with transparencies overlay and thus reduce the amount of the background to be seen:

[image]

When no anti-aliasing (font smoothing) is active you don't see a difference between the reference text and the case where multiple elements overlay (that example might not work for every browser or os):

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
}

* {
  font-smooth: never;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: none;
 }
```

```html
<p>overlayed text</p>
<p>overlayed text</p>
<p>overlayed text</p>
<p>overlayed text</p>
<div>reference text</div>
```

With anti-aliasing (font smoothing) is active you can see that the overlayed text looks bolder then the reference text.

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>overlayed text</p>
<p>overlayed text</p>
<p>overlayed text</p>
<p>overlayed text</p>
<div>reference text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It most probably have to do with anti-aliasing of the font. It causes edges to be semi-transparent, which when overlapped will cause them to be more opaque and therefore more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Because the properties on the text changes, right click and inspect element and you will be able to see this:

[image]

Comment: A 404 - image not found?

Comment: @NakarukatoshiUzumaki you cant see the image? https://gyazo.com/81b1af01bdba69d26e6517cddbefa6d4

Comment: I can see *that* link, but not the one on the answer itself

Comment: @NakarukatoshiUzumaki thats so weird, I'm assuming the guy who edited the answer saw it, and I can see it aswell.

Comment: I can't see anything other than an image with "404 - image not found" "The url you entered is invalid or expired." "ezgif.com"

Comment: @Stanley I don't really know why, but the link with which you answered me works as expected...

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Now's working, thanks @Viira!

Comment: It's still interesting that two letters above each other causes it to thicken.

Comment: @ShamPooSham definitely, but that's very likely to be a browser bug, nothing we/I haven't seen before

Comment: @Stanley I think that's what OP wondered. I think they know what is happening in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

It is because the second `<p>` is overlapping the first `<p>` which resulted in bolder font.

Just like how we draw lines on a white paper. At first the line will be thinner. If we keep draw lines repeatedly it will result in bolder line. Same concept is applied here.

To explain this better lets have a series of `p` here each with less `opacity`  overlapping one another.

**Single element opacity**

```css
p {opacity: 0.17;color:red;}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

**Multi element opacity**

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.17;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
<p>Test</p>
```

As you can see the `opacity: 0.17` is multiplied by 10 (number of elements) and resulted in a visible format.

Comment: I don't understand this explanation at all. Drawing on a screen is not the same as on paper. On paper more ink can get absorbed, leading to a stronger color or a thicker line (because of ink absorption by the paper) even assuming the pen puts ink down in exactly the same place, which is is unlikely. Whereas on a screen if a pixel is fired, it is fired - no 'absorption etc possibilies. The answer is more likely to be because on a screen rendering is of the two is not exactly in the same place, see some of the other answers why this may be.